# Two layouts with the same location in GLSL 4.4

Tags: opengl, glsl, texture-mapping

Is it possible to have two layouts with the same location equate to two different input variables of different types in a shader? Currently, my program is not explicitly assigning any location for the vertex, texture, normal vertex arrays. But in my shader, when I have selected the location 0 for both my vertex position and texture coords, it gives me a perfect output. I wanted to know if this is just a coincidence or is it really possible to assign to the same location? Here is my definition of the input variables in the vertex shader:

```
#version 440
layout (location = 0) in vec4 VertexPosition;
layout (location = 2) in vec4 VertexNormal;
layout (location = 0) in vec2 VertexTexCoord;
```

Comment: I just noticed vec2 and vec4. The attribute index is the same but the type is diffrent. This makes me want to learn ARB assembly because aint nobody got time to understand high-level shader programs.

Answer (score 4):

Technically... yes, you can. For Vertex Shader inputs (and *only* for vertex shader inputs), you can assign two variables to the same location. However, you *may not* attempt to read from both of them. You can dynamically select which one to read from, but it's undefined behavior if your shader takes a path that reads from both variables.

The relevant quote from the standard is:

> The one exception where component aliasing is permitted is for two input variables (not block members) to a vertex shader, which are allowed to have component aliasing.This vertex-variable component aliasing is intended only to support vertex shaders where each execution path accesses at most one input per each aliased component.

But this is stupid and pointless. *Don't do it*.

Comment: So I guess it is a matter of coincidence. It's just staggering how the output obj model has a perfect uv mapped texture applied to it. I will investigate more.

Comment: @shaveenk: Undefined behavior means *undefined behavior*. And that means it might simply work.